# jquery get syntax with php and mysql for input validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

This one is frustrating me.
To keep things simple.
I have a web page with an input and a p element

```
<input type=text name="findSong" id="findSong">
<p id = " songCheck">Search</p>
```

I have a php file that connects to the database fine but not sure if my query is proper.

What I am trying to do is use jquery .keypress event on the input findSong.  So as I type it keeps checking the database for a match. And then update the p element to something like 'Match Found'.

Here is my php file called songCheck.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";

$database = "karaoke";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$song = isset($_POST['findSong'])
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection

if (!$conn) {

    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}

$sql = "Select * From songlist  WHERE SongNum = '".$song."')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "Match Found"
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>
```

i need help with jquery returning if it is or is not in the database.  Thanks in advance

Here is the jquery.

```
$("input").keypress(function(){
    $.get("songCheck.php", function(data, status){
        document.getElementById('songCheck').innerHTML = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: We need to see jquery code.

Comment: oops sorry editing question!

Comment: There is an extra close bracket in `'".$song."')";`

Answer (score 1):

Try This one:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['findSong'])){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "karaoke";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    // Check connection

    if (!$conn) {

        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    }
    $song = $_POST["findSong"]);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM songlist WHERE SongNum = '$song'"; 
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
          echo "Match Found"
    } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Some explanation of what you have done and how this solves the question would improve the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Its more my jquery then anything doesnt seem to do anything on keypress